# How to compare two different column for opposite of one another in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result set that is a relationship table. I am converting their data from one schema to another. There relationship table as a relationship row for each person. so for example
if bill knows bob there is a row that has contactid and contactid1.

Contactid being the primary person in the relationship. In their system Bob would need to have a separate row with him being the primary.

so the rows in their DB would look like this

```
Contactid | Contactid1 | Description
123       | 456        |Gold Club Dinner
456       | 123        |Gold Club Dinner
```

Whereas in my schema the relationship looks like this

```
Contactid | Contactid1 | Description
123       | 456        |Gold Club Dinner
```

I need to know a way to get the top 1 for each group in the first db so that I don't end up with thousands of duplicates in the table structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know what's "right"?  Have you tried select top x...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select distinct
    case when contactID<contactID1 then contactID else contactID1 end , 
    case when contactID<contactID1 then contactID1 else contactID end ,
    description
from yourtable
```

I would argue, however, that both these designs are wrong, and should be normalised.

Comment: This is a nice one ! +1

Comment: The query works great if I only use the case statements but if you add any more columns such as the description column like you have in the query. I get almost the same result as a select * because in most cases the description is different between rows so they are still treated as distinct rows.